# Regarding azure login to different resources

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Currently i'm authenticating to a resource one which is my backend. But using the same access token i tried to get data from Microsoft graph api it's giving

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "Authentication_MissingOrMalformed",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en",
            "value": "Access Token missing or malformed."
        },
        "date": "2018-02-22T10:37:53",
        "requestId": "381cf386-6065-422b-b561-164ed17dcfdf",
        "values": null
    }
}
```

How to resolve this. Is it possible to access both with one access token

Answer (score 0):

No. An access token is always meant for one API/resource.

You must get two access tokens. You can use the refresh token or authorization code to get two.

Comment: Ok how can i send the refresh token and get it? couldn't find any details regarding this

Comment: That depends on your authentication setup. But typically you get a refresh token together with the access token. Though if you use ADAL the refresh token is hidden from you.

Comment: ok i tried using ADAL but couldn't access my backend resource using the received access token

Comment: You should probably make a new question. Describe in detail what you did and what doesn't work along with the relevant code.